# java .get(int index) getting just one value, get(0) or get(1) returns correct value but only .get(1) is saved to database

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

My array has a size of 3 and i want to save all three to my database however, only one keeps adding. I'm using .get(int index). Here is my code

```
    Sales sales= new Sales();
    for(int i = 0; i < drugname.size(); i++) {
        sales.setDrugcategory(drugcategory);
        sales.setQuantityrequested(quantityrequested);
        sales.setTotal(total);
        sales.setTotalbill(totalbill);
        System.out.println(drugname.size());
        System.out.println(i);
        sales.setDrugname(drugname.get(i));
        sales.setPrice(price.get(i));
        }
```

Am I getting it wrong somewhere?
These are my getter and setter methods

```
@Entity
public class Sales {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
public String drugcategory;
public String drugname;
public String quantityrequested;
public float price;
public String total;
public String totalbill;
public String dateofsale;


public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDateofsale() {
    return dateofsale;
}

public void setDateofsale(String dateofsale) {
    this.dateofsale = dateofsale;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDrugcategory() {
    return drugcategory;
}

public void setDrugcategory(String drugcategory) {
    this.drugcategory = drugcategory;
}

public String getDrugname() {
    return drugname;
}

public void setDrugname(String drugname) {
    this.drugname = drugname;
}

public String getQuantityrequested() {
    return quantityrequested;
}

public void setQuantityrequested(String quantityrequested) {
    this.quantityrequested = quantityrequested;
}



public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getTotalbill() {
    return totalbill;
}

public void setTotalbill(String totalbill) {
    this.totalbill = totalbill;
}
}
```

Comment: You keep on changing properties of the same instance. Do you mean to do that, or should you move the `Sales sales = ...` line inside the loop (presumably as well as the line which commits the instance)?

Comment: moving it inside the loop flags an error.

Comment: The size of my array is correct but i think the . get(I) is the one with the problem.

Comment: No, `get` isn't the problem, `setDrugname` and `setPrice` are.

Comment: Also, please, please follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I will work on the naming conventions, thanks. I'm still amateur at using java. I really dont know how the setter methods are the problem and i dont have any error in my console. I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the same object. Move creation of the object into the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < drugname.size(); i++) {
    Sales sales = new Sales();
    sales.setDrugcategory(drugcategory);
    sales.setQuantityrequested(quantityrequested);
    sales.setTotal(total);
    sales.setTotalbill(totalbill);
    System.out.println(drugname.size());
    System.out.println(i);
    sales.setDrugname(drugname.get(i));
    sales.setPrice(price.get(i));
}
```

Also try to use camel case in names so instead of `drugname` use `drugName`, it makes code easier to read :-)